# Appropriate function for two Gaussians

Tags: functions, exponential-function, normal-distribution

I'm searching for a $y(x)$ function that will produce normalized two Gaussians with a distance, something that looks like:

[image]

The picture is a bit-misleading, I need one that they do not cross each other at all.

Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: A single function cannot "cross each other". What about taking the sum ?

Comment: the sum will not be normalized

Comment: divide the sum by two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take something like $$f(x)=\frac1{\color{red}2\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\exp\{-\frac{x^2}{2}\}\times I_{\{x\leq5\}}+\exp\{-\frac{(x-10)^2}{2}\}\times I_{\{x>5\}}\right)$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what is I though?

Comment: You are welcome! $I$ is an indicator function which takes a value of $1$ if its argument is TRUE, and zeor otherwise.

Comment: The normalization is approximate. The smaller the distance, the more this will become apparent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for bringing up the issue: that was the reason I used a red color for the normalization $\color{red}{2}$. All in all OP seems not to care much about technical issues, he simply needed a function and I tried to give him an idea ...

Comment: @Math-fun: no, read the comments to the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't see the point you are trying to make :-) It though seems that OP is happy with the simple mix with an indicator function.

Comment: @Math-fun: the OP clearly insists to have a normalized function.He accepted the answer unknowingly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you think then that the problem is the normalization? Or the "connecting" point? Feel free to correct of course :-)

Comment: @Math-fun: hem, should I quote "the sum will not be normalized" ??? By the way, the OP never said "not to care much about technical issues".